# Is it possible to use CASE statement on dynamically populated DropdownList?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have a DropDownList that is dynamically populated from SQL Server database.

Currently, the DropDownList has 2 values, 0.20 and 0.30. However, users have informed us that they have several more values to add to the DropDownList.

If one of the users' clients presents water level of 0.20, they receive a discount of $100 or less.

The rest of the DropDownList values must receive $50 or less discount.

I am trying to use a CASE statement that ensures clients with 0.20 receive $100 or less discount and the rest $50 or less discount but I am stuck on how to handle the rest of the DropDownList values.

This is what I have been trying so far and I would like to know if it is possible to use CASE statement to handle this.

```
protected bool CheckWaterLevel(string wsize, decimal amt)
{
    bool valueOK = false;
    switch (wsize)
    {
        case "0.20":
            if (amt <= 100)
                valueOK = true;
                break;

        case "0.30":
            if (amt <= 50)
                valueOK = true;
            break;
    }
    return valueOK;
}
```

In a nutshell, is it possible to replace case "0.30" with the values of DropDownList with the exception of 0.20?

The DropDownList control ID is ddlWaterLevels

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<br /><br /><br />
<div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblWater" runat="server" Text="Water Size" Width="100px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_watersizes" placeholder="Enter new Water Size" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_amount" placeholder="Enter amount" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" Text="Add It" onclick="btn_add_Click"
            Width="100px" /><br /><br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWater" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlWater_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter new water size" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

C#:

```
`using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string str;
        SqlCommand com;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                dropbind();
            }
        }

        protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlWater.Items.Clear();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            com = new SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.CommandText = "insert into WaterVolume(WaterSizes,Amount)values(@tsizes,@amount)";
            com.Parameters.Clear();
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsizes", txt_watersizes.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txt_amount.Text);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("Records successfully inserted");
            clear();
            dropbind();
        }
        private void clear()
        {
            txt_watersizes.Text = "";
            txt_amount.Text = "";
    }
    private void dropbind()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT WaterSizes FROM WaterVolume", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        ddlWater.DataSource = dt;
                        ddlWater.DataTextField = "WaterSizes";
                        ddlWater.DataValueField = "WaterSizes";
                        ddlWater.DataBind();
                        ddlWater.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "" });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void FetchData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        con.Open();
            String sql = "SELECT Amount FROM WaterVolume WHERE WaterSizes = '" + ddlWater.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    //    cmd.Connection.Open();
    //    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //If you want to get mutiple data from the database then you need to write a simple looping
            TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString();
        }
   //     cmd.Connection.Close();


    }
  }
    protected void ddlWater_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FetchData();

    }
}
```

This is a better solution.
Obviously, I was overthinking it.

As you can see, a user selects water size, a textbox is automatically populated with the corresponding amount.

Since this is an internal app managed by only two people, and per their instruction, if there is a new water size, they don't have to contact us, they just enter the new water size and amount and voila, they are ready to go.

I just need to add some validations to ensure user cannot submit without entering data into the two boxes.